# Getting White Screen instead of SplashScreen with initial app loading after installing - Ionic App

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

Hi I am Getting White Screen instead of SplashScreen with initial app loading after installing - Ionic App
Here is my ionic info

```
Cordova CLI: 6.5.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 3.8.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 3.0.1
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Linux 4.4
Node Version: v6.11.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Can you please check with it 
Here is my part of config.xml

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="true" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="30000" />
<preference name="SplashScreenSpinnerColor" value="white" />
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="700000" />
```

Splash Intialization:

```
setTimeout(() => {
this.splashScreen.hide();
}, 0)
```

Please check with it

Comment: this is my setting in config file try this one                                                                              
   <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2700" />
    <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false" />

Comment: also let me know your app.js code in which have you handled your navigator.splashcreen?

Comment: didnot worked ... app.js splash related lines updated

Comment: I have added in app initializeApp()  in this.platform.ready()

Comment: instead of this.splashScreen.hide use if (navigator.splashscreen) {
            navigator.splashscreen.hide();
        } also remove setTimeout()

Comment: applied , but didnot worked

Comment: I am having issue with android mobile while asking at camera permission time

Comment: camera permission time? i dont understand it

Comment: When app is installed , it is asking for allow access to photos ,media . At that instance splash screen is white in color

Comment: one thing you can do it that is you can move your permission related code after login or after app is completely initialized mean after the first page or start up page is render